# Getting a stick through a corridor

Tags: geometry

[image: See this image]

I know the the maximum length of the stick can be $\sqrt 2$. In order to get this stick through, there must be a point $R$ where the stick turns around. How can I determine where this point $R$ lies?

Comment: Right now I think the stick moves tangent to a circle.

Comment: I think the center of rotation itself traces some specific locus.

Comment: When do you conclude it's "through"? Both endpoints of the segment beyond the intersection square?

Comment: Apparently the corridor has width 0.5?

Answer (score 0):

For reasons of symmetry, $R$ should be on the diagonal line $x=y$.

Drawing a radius from $R$ to the corner at $(0.5,0.5)$ would indicate where the midpoint of the segment is as reaches its tightest point in passing the intersection. Continuing to rotate the segment attached to that radius, it could at best become flush with the wall when the segment becomes horizontal or vertical.

This creates a picture of a $45-45-90$ triangle with leg length $r$ and diagonal length $r\sqrt{2}=r+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, where $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ is the diagonal measurement of the intersection square.

Solving this you would get $r=1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. This gives you the coordinates of a center of rotation at $R=(r,r)$